# Windows 7 upgrade and Grub boot loader

Tags: windows-7, upgrade

I currently have a PC with Vista and Ubuntu installed, using the Grub boot loader to select the OS. The two OSes are on separate partitions.

If I were to ugrade the Vista installation to Windows 7, will it affect the grub loader? If it does, how would I re-instate the grub loader after the update?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, Windows 7 will break your GRUB. You can get it back like so:

> 1) Boot off the LiveCD
>
> 2) Open a Terminal and type in the
>   following commands, noting that the
>   first command will put you into the
>   grub “prompt”, and the next 3 commands
>   will be executed there. Also note that
>   hd0,0 implies the first hard drive and
>   the first partition on that drive,
>   which is where you probably installed
>   grub to during installation. If not,
>   then adjust accordingly.
>
> ```
> sudo grub
>
> > root (hd0,0)
>
> > setup (hd0)
>
> > quit
> ```
>
> Reboot (removing the livecd), and your
>   boot menu should be back.

Check [The How-To Geek's guide](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/reinstall-ubuntu-grub-bootloader-after-windows-wipes-it-out/) for more details, in case you don't see Windows in the boot menu after this configuration.

Comment: You should use `grub> find /boot/grub/stage1` to find where root is. And grub uses quit, not exit, as I found out yesterday

Comment: That looks good. I'll give it a go.

Comment: An extra note: if, like me, you forgot which partition number Ubuntu was installed on, typing "root (hd0," and then <tab> displays the available partitions, just pick the one that it identifies as a readable partition (it doesn't recognise the NTFS partitions).