# No GRUB after re-installing Windows

Tags: linux, grub, fedora-12

I have Windows and I installed Fedora 12 on a separate partition.

However, I had a problem with my windows XP SP 3 and had to install Windows on my C drive.

When I re-boot I on longer get the GRUB loader displayed so cannot boot into Fedora.

Is there anything I can do?

Comment: Don't know a fix offhand, but windows basically installed its own bootloader over GRUB. Perhaps adding linux to windows bootloader will help. What version of windows do you have?

Comment: Actually, AFAIK the Windows bootloader won't load Linux, you have to reinstall GRUB or a different bootloader to load both Windows and *nix.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to reinstall grub.  Here a couple other questions that should help you out:

- [How to fix GRUB after Windows breaks it, and how to edit the GRUB menu](https://superuser.com/questions/50684/how-to-fix-grub-after-windows-breaks-it-and-how-to-edit-the-grub-menu)
- [Repair grub mbr and /boot using ubuntu 9.04 live CD](https://superuser.com/questions/25168/repair-grub-mbr-and-boot-using-ubuntu-9-04-live-cd)
- [Windows 7 upgrade and Grub boot loader](https://superuser.com/questions/61392/windows-7-upgrade-and-grub-boot-loader)

Comment: I just reinstalled WinXP, and Rob Kam's answer from the first link worked swell and very quick. I used my Ubuntu 9.04 LiveCD, BTW. And... Ubuntu 9.10 switched to GRUB 2, so don't use that for restoring an earlier version of GRUB. I don't know if Fedora has switched to that, but just a heads-up.

Answer (score 3):

If you installed Fedora from a cd and it has live capabilities you can boot into the cd and repair grub via that. When you install windows it replaces the boot manager with its own.

You can check out [this as well](http://dailypackage.fedorabook.com/index.php?/archives/158-System-Recovery-Week-Rescue-Mode-and-Reinstalling-Grub.html)

Answer (score 2):

Download, burn to cd and boot from the .iso available at supergrubdisk.com - it will find your previous grub and reinstall it.