# How do I recover grub after installing Windows?

Tags: ubuntu, grub

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [No GRUB after re-installing windows](https://superuser.com/questions/85598/no-grub-after-re-installing-windows)

Hello all,

I had dual booted my computer with windows 7 and ubuntu.... Now windows 7 has crashed so I would have to reinstall it....

However this would mean that NTLDR would be reinstalled over grub ...

Is there any way to get grub back again than to reinstall ubuntu tooo.....

Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Recovering Ubuntu After Installing Windows](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows) guide from the Ubuntu Documentation explains how.

Answer (score 0):

I used this article, found via another question on here.

[How to reinstall / fix GRUB2 after installing / dual booting Windows 7 or Ubuntu 10.10](http://bithacker.blogspot.com/2010/10/how-to-reinstall-fix-grub2-after.html)

Comment: Not sure why I was downvoted, this worked for me.