# After installing Windows to a separate SSD, BIOS no longer shows other disk with GRUB on an EFI boot partition

Tags: linux, boot, multi-boot, grub

I have a Fedora installation on one of my SSDs with GRUB installed to an EFI boot partition. I installed Windows 10 using a live installation image to the other SSD, and now I cannot find Disk1 (the SSD w/ Fedora and GRUB) in BIOS, and hence cannot boot into it. What happened, and how can I restore my ability to boot this disk?

[Windows disk manager, displaying that the EFI boot partition still exists](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GAtkA.png)

Comment: Check out the related links such as No Grub after re-installing Windows https://superuser.com/questions/85598/no-grub-after-re-installing-windows?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You have UEFI, not BIOS!** Although the (new) UEFI performs the same function as the (old) BIOS did, **UEFI is not BIOS**, and the way it boots one or more OSes is entirely different.

According to your Windows Disk Manager screenshot there's only one ESP, the EFI System partition (correct) so, if Windows boots, everything is as it should be.

You won't need to change drive boot order. Actually this concept is mostly applicable to BIOS/MBR systems although in an UEFI system with multiple drives we may need to assure the drive containing the ESP is at the top of the list. Again, if Windows boots then the correct drive - Disk 1 - is being used, even though Windows is installed in a different drive, Disk 0.

Regarding your specific case, because you installed Windows after Fedora, it changed the bootloader order (different from drive order) to its own (Windows bootloader manager). The Windows installer did so in order to make the installation go faster and smoothly due to the sevral reboots needed.

All you need to do now is to open the UEFI settings (what you 'wrongly' assume is BIOS) and change it back to Fedora (Grub). Then boot Fedora and run

`sudo grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/EFI/fedora/grub.cfg`

to update Grub and include the newly installed Windows.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer and corrections. Had no option in visual UEFI to change bootloader order, so I disabled SecureBoot, enabled UEFI shell and booted into it, found grubx64.efi in fs1:\EFI\fedora, and executed it (I also saw that Windows installed its bootloader onto my EFI partition on Disk1 into its own folder). Athough running the command you provided added Windows to GRUB, I needed to change the boot order which I did in Fedora with sudo efibootmgr --bootorder xxxx,xxxx (my UEFI shell didn't have bcfg, and this was simpler to me than making a startup.nsh script).

Comment: That will do it as well. :) Furthermore, what you describe is expected. The ESP should contain the .efi files for all installed OSes. When booting Fedora (Grub) and selecting Windows it chainloads to the Windows bootloader.